# Change decorator to implement in new module

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator

I have some class with a field `spent_times`. `spent_times` is a list and all methods of this class write some information, which is valuable for logging.

Also, I have a decorator, which calculate execution time for every function and write it to `spent_times`.

This is realization of my decorator:

```
def timing(message):
    def wrap(function):
        def called(*args, **kwargs):
            time_start = timer()
            spent_time = round(timer() - time_start, 5)

            if not args:
                return function(*args, **kwargs), spent_time

            obj = args[0]
            if hasattr(obj, "spent_times"):
                obj.spent_times.append("{}={:.5f}".format(message, spent_time))
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                logging.warning('Decorator allows to set spent_time attribute!')
        return called
    return wrap
```

As you can see in my decorator there is a check, if the calling function has attribute *self*.

If it has, than I can write needed info in list `spent_times` on the spot, if it does not have, than decorator returns time spent on execution and function itself.

I am using this decorator in one single module and second case (when no *self* found) belongs to some other functions in this module, which does not belong to class, where spent_time list is defined, but I execute them **inside** my class, so I am able to realize for example the following structure:

This is declaration of "outer" function

```
def calc_users(requests, priority):
     # .....
```

And inside my class I execute it and update my spent_time list  this way:

```
 response, spent_time = calc_users(requests, priority)
 self.class_obj.spent_times.append("user_calculation={:.5f}".format(spent_time))
```

which is not very nice, but it is working at least.

Now,  I moved a few functions of my class in **different** new module and I would like to use the same decorator timing.

Can someone help me to implement this realization of timing in new module. I do not know, what can I do to update my `spent_times` list now.

These two modules will work at the same time and I cannot create object of class and pass it as an argument to new module, because (as far as I understand it) there will be two objects and spent_times will not be updated correctly.

Maybe there is a way to pass a reference to `spent_times` somehow, but I do not want to change arguments of my functions in new module, since I think in this case principle of shared responsibility will be broken (decorator is responsible for logging, function for its action).

So how to improve decorator or how to pass `spent_times` list to a new module?

Any help will be greatly appreciate!

P.S.

Maybe make `spent_times` a global variable? (in the very worst case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A global list seems fine but you can also use a class and create a singleton by deleting the class after instantiation. This prevents from creating another another instance:

```
# mymodule.py

from timeit import default_timer as timer

class Timing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.spent_times = []

    def __call__(self, message):
        def wrap(function):
            def called(*args, **kwargs):
                time_start = timer()
                spent_time = round(timer() - time_start, 5)
                self.spent_times.append("{}={:.5f}".format(message, spent_time))
                return function(*args, **kwargs)
            return called
        return wrap 

timing = Timing()
del Timing # prevent another instance
```

Now import in another module:

```
from mymodule import timing

@timing('Hello')
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

The special method `__call__` makes an instance of a class behave like a function, i.e. it is callable with `()`.
The advantage it that you can use `self.attr` instead of a global variable.

The deletion of the class after instantiation prevents from creating another instance. This is called a singleton. Now all your timings end up in the same list no matter how often you use `timing` as a decorator.

Comment: Vielen Dank! 
Das ist aber nicht so leich zu verstehen.. (Thank you! Though it does not look so easy to understand)

Comment: Added some more explanation.

Comment: Thank you for more detailed explanation! I see another task here, now I must determine  deleting timing in mymodule.py. How can I find out the moment, when timing must be deleted..?

Comment: You don't have to delete the class `Timing`. Only if you want to make sure there is only one list wit measured times.